# Django: Why is my jQuery POST url changing when it hits the server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a script running the following `post` to a Django backend:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                                       
    $('.arrow-up, .arrow-down').click(function() {                                  
        var myElement = $(this);                                                    
        var url = myElement.data('url');                                            
        myElement.addClass('hidden');                                               
        var spinner = myElement.siblings('.spinning');                              
        spinner.removeClass('hidden');                                              
        debugger;                                                                   
        $.post({                                                                    
            url: url,                                                               
            // TODO: implement this better.                                         
            data: {vote: 'test'},                                                   
            dataType: 'json',                                                       
            success: function() {                                                   
                myElement.toggleClass('arrow-selected');                            
                spinner.addClass('hidden');                                         
                myElement.removeClass('hidden');                                    
            },                                                                      
            error: function() {                                                     
                spinner.addClass('hidden');                                         
                myElement.removeClass('hidden');                                    
                // TODO: make this link to the signup modal.                        
                alert('You must be logged in to vote');                             
            }                                                                       
        });                                                                         
    });                                                                             
});
```

When I inspect the console at the `debugger;` statement, the `url` parameter is `"http://localhost:8000/item/6/1/"`.

However, when the `POST` reaches my django server, it returns a 404 to a different url, the current `location` with `[object%20Object]` appended:

```
"POST /lists/4/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 404 2677
```

Why is this happening, and how can I make my ajax call to the desired url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the url as part of the form data. I believe it should be:

```
$.post(url, {vote:'test'})
```

Actually, the entire format you're using is better for $.ajax, so maybe it might just be better to change that post to ajax and add a type: 'POST' like

```
    $.ajax({                                                                    
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',                                                              
        // TODO: implement this better.                                         
        data: {vote: 'test'},                                                   
        dataType: 'json',                                                       
        success: function() {                                                   
            myElement.toggleClass('arrow-selected');                            
            spinner.addClass('hidden');                                         
            myElement.removeClass('hidden');                                    
        },                                                                      
        error: function() {                                                     
            spinner.addClass('hidden');                                         
            myElement.removeClass('hidden');                                    
            // TODO: make this link to the signup modal.                        
            alert('You must be logged in to vote');                             
        }                                                                       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating url in code

Check line  `var url = myElement.data('url');`

Comment: No, per my question I inspect the `url` parameter at the `debugger;` statement and it's correct.

Comment: why do not you try to alert url. I was saying that url value get changed as you trigger click event.